# Grouping information in Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, schema, database-schema, schema-design

A simple question. Suppose I have 4 numbers that describe a box. Should I add them in the form of: box:{top, bottom, left, right} or keep them as 4 separate fields of the document?

I would appreciate a reason to, or not to, choose or not choose a particular one. Bare in mind this will used everywhere. Unless I shouldn't !?

Comment: how does a number represent a point? do you mean a coordinate pair?

Comment: Take the 4 corners of a box. any two points on a side have 1 value in common. thus its more efficient to store them as 4 numbers, each representing a side. to get the top-left corner, for example, consider the top number value and the left number value.

Comment: ah I see - the box sides are parallel to your x and y axes.

Comment: Well, yes :D nicely put. what about the problem at hand?

Comment: IMHO I would always store data in the format that will allow the most flexibility when querying - do you know how you will be accessing this data?  I don't think a generic answer really exists...

Comment: I will always ALWAYS query those values together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put them all into a single `box: {top:1, bottom:0, left:0, right:1}` style field as the two approaches are functionally equivalent but this way would let you more easily include/exclude the group of fields in projections when needed by just referencing `box: 1` or `box: 0`.